# Click Event On Dynamically Added TextViews in Android

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

I am trying to add 20 textviews and assign a onclick to dynamically added textviews. Problem is whenever i try to click any of the dynamic textiview. It always fires up click event of last added textview.

Here is my code:

```
EditText s;
EditText t;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout containerLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        TextView dynaText = new TextView(this);

        dynaText.setText("Some text " + i);
        dynaText.setTextSize(30);
        dynaText.setTag("" + i);

        dynaText.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);
        // Set the location of your textView.

        dynaText.setPadding(0, (i * 30), 0, 0);

        containerLayout.addView(dynaText);
    }

}

OnClickListener btnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
        TextView tv = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(2);
        // Integer pos = (Integer) tv.getTag();
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Toast " + v.getTag(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

};
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
OnClickListener btnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
          Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Toast " + v.getTag(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

};
```

**Update:**

The reason why you are clicking the last `TextView` is because it is just so big.. You are increasing the padding with each loop and when you click somewhere, it will always hit the last `View` because it is overlaying the others. Try a `LinearLayout` and remove the padding like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout containerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            TextView dynaText = new TextView(this);

            dynaText.setText("Some text " + i);
            dynaText.setTextSize(30);
            dynaText.setTag("" + i);
            dynaText.setOnClickListener(this);

            containerLayout.addView(dynaText);
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do stuff
    }

}
```

But having your problem solved.. I think a `ListView` would suit your purpose :)

Comment: Thanks Marijin, that worked. Thanks a million. I am using custom listview adapter and there i would like to add dynamic textview to list row items.

Answer (score 4):

1) you should make your `TextViews` **Clickable** first :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        TextView dynaText = new TextView(this);

        dynaText.setText("Some text " + i);
        dynaText.setTextSize(30);
        dynaText.setTag("" + i);
        dynaText.setClickable(true);//make your TextView Clickable
        dynaText.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);
        // Set the location of your textView.

        dynaText.setPadding(0, (i * 30), 0, 0);

        containerLayout.addView(dynaText);
    }
```

2) modify your `onClickListener` :

```
OnClickListener btnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
          Log.d("btnClickListener", ""-----TextView Clicked : "+v.getTag());
          Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "TextView Clicked : "+v.getTag(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

};
```

EDIT : you are adding your `TextViews` one over one . that's why the click event fires on the last one added. 
try to use a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` , or try to add each new TextView bellow the previous one :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        TextView dynaText = new TextView(this);

        dynaText.setText("Some text " + i);
        dynaText.setId(i+1);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        if(i!=0)
         params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, i);
         dynaText.setLayoutParams(params);
        dynaText.setTextSize(30);
        dynaText.setTag("" + i);

        dynaText.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);

        containerLayout.addView(dynaText);
    }
```

Comment: Not to any advantage Houcine,Still the same

Comment: change the v.getContext with : YourActivity.this

Comment: that's because you add each textView over the previous textView . try to use a linearLayout with android:orientation="vertical" or via relativeLayout you should add each TextView bellow the previous one . see my edits

Answer (score 1):

Do in the following way to get the clicked data

Declare a variable

```
int sCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        TextView dynaText = new TextView(this);
        dynaText.setId(1000+sCount);
        dynaText.setText("Some text " + i);
        dynaText.setTextSize(30);
        dynaText.setTag("" + i);

        dynaText.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);
        // Set the location of your textView.

        dynaText.setPadding(0, (i * 30), 0, 0);

        containerLayout.addView(dynaText);
    }
OnClickListener btnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
        TextView tv = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(2);
        tv.addFocusables(null, v.getId(), 0);
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Toast " + tv.getText(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

};
```

This works fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use anonymous instances for `OnClickListener` and create different instance of listener for each view. Something like this:

```
dynaText.setPadding(0, (i * 30), 0, 0);
dynaText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ((TextView) v).getText();

}
});
containerLayout.addView(dynaText);
```

Comment: How did you know that it's not? i'm 100% sure this is what your are looking for.